# Work around DynamoDb Transaction Conflict Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

My model represents users with unique names. In order to achieve that I store user and its name as 2 separate items using TransactWriteItems. The approximate structure looks like this:

```
PK                  | data
--------------------------------
userId#<userId>     | {user data}
userName#<userName> | {userId: <userId>}
```

Data arrives to a lambda from a Kinesis stream. If one lambda invocation processes an "insert" event and another lambda request comes in about at the same time (the difference could be 5 milliseconds) the "update" event causes a `TransactionConflictException: Transaction is ongoing for the item` error.

Should I just re-try to run update again in a second or so? I couldn't really find a resolution strategy.

Answer (score 0):

That implies you’re getting data about the same user in quick succession and both writes are hitting the same items. One succeeds while the other exceptions out.

Is it always duplicate data? If you’re sure it is, then you can ignore the second write. It would be a no-op.

Is it different data? Then you’ve got to decide how to handle that conflict. You’ll have one dataset in the database and a different dataset live in your code. That’s a business logic question not database question.